# How to find a match skipping the tag using regular expression?

Tags: .net, html, regex

i want to write a regex where it should ignore tag which is present between the string.

e.g.,
here is my string

```
<p>hi this is a reg<del>U</del><ins>u</ins>lar expression match</p>
```

i want a regular expression to find "regular" from above string,
the match should find whole word including tags i.e., `reg<del>U</del><ins>u</ins>lar`

here case can be ignored.

plz help me.. thanks in advance

Comment: Gah! [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/383609)! If you insist on using regex, what language are you doing this in? With jQuery, it's trivial to get just the text, for example.

Comment: Ignoring the tags would mean that your string becomes `regUular` (because those tags have meaning, you know). So what exactly do you want to ignore? @JamWaffles: This also would need to be taken into account with a jQuery solution, making it nontrivial.

Comment: @Tim Very true, I didn't see that extra `U` in the HTML.

Comment: @JamWaffles i was using c# in asp.net

Comment: @TimPietzcker i want to ignore the content which is inside the <del> tag, so my match will be just 'regular' not 'regUular'

Comment: So is it *just*  the `<del>` tag you want to ignore with its contents? And all other tags should be treated like they weren't even there?

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes.. the same what u said is my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get a robust solution in regex. At any rate, it won't be very readable. Here, in verbose form, is a regex that conforms to your revised specifications. Note that it fails to handle `<del>` tags that contain any nested tags - that's impossible to do with nsregularexpressions.

```
\b        # Start of word
r         # Match r
(?:       # Match either
 <del>    #  <del>
 [^<>]*   #  any characters besides angle brackets
 </del>   #  </del>
|         # or
 <[^<>]*> #  any other tag
)*        # End of alternation
e         # Match e
(?:<del>[^<>]*</del>|<[^<>]*>)*  # etc...
g
(?:<del>[^<>]*</del>|<[^<>]*>)*
u
(?:<del>[^<>]*</del>|<[^<>]*>)*
l
(?:<del>[^<>]*</del>|<[^<>]*>)*
a
(?:<del>[^<>]*</del>|<[^<>]*>)*
r
\b
```

Comment: this is fine when i am dealing with large string lik the example i given, bt for all the general cases it wont help know..

Comment: and one more thing is that for me there will be only tags in between the characters, above regex will match all charcters other than tags also....

Comment: @harish: I've updated the regex. It works on your example and follows your new specs closely.

Comment: thanks.. its working fine, i will check this with different combinations and let u know if any prob exists

Comment: hi.. can u check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474742/skip-xml-content-while-doing-regex-search-and-replace

Comment: i am struggling to find the exact method(or answer) for that post.. plz help me....

Answer (score 0):

You really need some form of HTML parser here. Regexps are unsuited for HTML and you'll spend your time refining and tweaking to try and cover *all* the edge cases (which you just can't).