# Skip XML content while doing regex search and replace

Tags: xml, regex, full-text-search, xsd, search-engine

I have a xml string as follows

```
<root>
    <A id="1">This is an example</A>
    <B id="2">
            <C id="3">this is tag c</C>
    </B>
    <D id="4">this is tag d</D>
    <E id="5">
            <F id="6">this is tag f</F>
            <G id="7">this is tag g</G>
               .
               .
               .
    </E>
</root>
```

here i just want to search the word `tag` and replace it by `Xml Tag` using regex(Regular Expression), and i dont want to search that word inside the element `<E>...</E>` i.e., i want to skip element `<E>...</E>` while search and replace.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this varies with your environment, and with what you mean, exactly, by saying you want to skip element E.  In XSLT or XQuery, a simple way to find text nodes that match a regular expression anywhere outside of E elements would be

```
//text()[not(ancestor::E)][matches(.,'tag')]
```

In other environments, it may or may not be convenient to do something analogous.

Note that if "skipping element E" means you want content of the form

```
<A>This is a tricky example
   of the word t<E>hi, mom!</E>ag.</A>
```

to return a hit on the search for "tag", then you will need a more complex solution.

Comment: hi.. thanks for reply.. using XML DOM or XQuery/XSLT it is ok... but sometimes my match could be a regular expression, so is there any way to do it...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  Is there any way to use a regular expression in the search?  Yes, as shown in my example:  the second argument of the `matches()` function is a regular expression.

Comment: is this  'matches()' supports in .net?